# How to call Oracle procedures having OracleTypes.ARRAY as IN and OUT parameter using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a procedure which takes OracleType as IN and flag as OUT.

PROCEDURE SaveDetails (
             i_details_list IN DETAILS_TYPE_LIST,
             Flg OUT NUMBER );

Desc DETAILS_TYPE;
TYPE DETAILS_TYPE AS OBJECT(
 Details_Id                     NUMBER(1),
 Country                    VARCHAR2(2),
 phone_number                   NUMBER(9),
 )

Currently we are calling this using JDBC CallableStatement.
I want to call this procedure from Hibernate. 
Please can you suggest the exact syntax. It would be very great helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same JDBC CallableStatement but use Hibernate Session to retrieve the Connection.

```
Connection conn = getSession().connection();
CallableStatment stat = conn.prepareCall("{CALL SaveDetails(?,?)}");
```

Hope this helps.